# Haskell 'Either' data type and readability?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm learning 'Either' data structures in Haskell and have written the following:

```
type PhoneBook = [(String, String)] 
createPhoneBook :: PhoneBook --Use function to generate instance of type
createPhoneBook = [("betty","1212-232"),
                   ("billy", "3443-434"),
                   ("derdre", "3232-221")]

data PresentInPhoneBook = Present | NotPresent deriving (Show, Eq) --Either 
type IsPresent = String
type IsNotPresent = String

checkPhoneBook :: String -> PhoneBook -> Either IsPresent IsNotPresent
checkPhoneBook name pb = if foldRes == True then Left "Match" else Right "No Match"
where 
    foldRes = foldl (\acc (key,value) -> if key == name then True else acc) False pb
```

Are there any improvements to make this code more readable?

I appreciate its a trivial example, but I'm just learning at this stage.

Comment: SO isn't a good site for code review, but it seems to me you want `checkPhoneBook :: String -> PhoneBook -> Bool`, or `... -> PresentInPhoneBook` would be okay too, if you have a reason to use a special type for that property.

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: Why use a type with as many values as `String` for `IsPresent` (resp. `IsNotPresent`) when you only plan on using the one value `"Match"` (resp. `"No Match"`)? It would make much more sense to make them types that only have one value in the first place like `type IsPresent = (); type IsNotPresent = ()`. But then you get `Either () ()`, which is basically the same to the machine as `Bool` or `PresentInPhoneBook` but less readable to humans. So at the end of all these refactorings, you end up at one of those two types instead of using `Either` or the `IsPresent`/`IsNotPresent` types at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like that:

```
import Data.Maybe (isJust)

checkPhoneBook :: String -> PhoneBook -> PresentInPhoneBook
checkPhoneBook name pb = isJust (lookup name pb)
```

There is not reason for use to have `checkPhoneBook` return `Either IsPresent IsNotPresent`. Just return `PresentInPhoneBook`. In this case it would also be ok to return a `Bool`. Also take a note of [lookup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) (that I use above). It returns a `Maybe` value, so you can use it to lookup a name as well as to figure out if a name exists in the phone book.

Comment: What are the scenarios where using 'Either' is helpful?

Comment: @barbrac When you have to return some value for each of the two cases.

Comment: @barbrac Think of `Either a b` as a generalization of `Maybe b`. `Right y` is used in the same way as `Just y`, but `Left x` allows you to specify a different value `x :: a` for each possible error, instead of just one catch-all return value of `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this

```
if foldRes == True then
```

by accident, or do you find it more readable than just

```
if foldRes then
```

In the latter case, I'd propose

```
if (foldRes == True) == True then
```

which must be, by extension, even more readable.

Comment: A very valid comment (it baffles me why it is true that so many people think it is a good idea to state redundant truthness by being redundant), but not an answer.

Comment: @leftaroundabout question was for improvements that make code more readable.